# json4s NoSuchMethodError when trying to save PipelineModel

Tags: scala, apache-spark, json4s

I am trying to perform a simple operation of saving a spark `PipelineModel` to hdfs via the `save` method.
I get the following exception even when trying to run spark's own example ([see here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/ml-pipeline.html#saving-and-loading-pipelines))

My code is fairly simple and tries to use only `spark.ml` `PipelineStage`s
package org.apache.spark.ml.util

```
import org.apache.spark.ml._
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature._
import org.scalatest.FunSuite


class Foo extends FunSuite {

... create spark context/session/sql context somewhere ...

    test("bar") {
        import sqlContext.implicits._
        val df = sparkContext.parallelize(
        (1, 4, "TH") ::
        (2, 5, "TH") ::
        (3, 6, "TH") ::
        (4, 7, "TH") ::
        (5, 8, "US") ::
        (6, 9, "US") :: Nil).toDF("id", "x", "a")

        val tr0 = new StringIndexer().setInputCol("a").setOutputCol("a_ind")
        val tr1 = new OneHotEncoder().setInputCol("a_ind").setOutputCol("a_vec").setDropLast(false)
        val tr2 = new PolynomialExpansion().setDegree(3).setInputCol("x").setOutputCol("x_vec")
        val tr3 = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(Array("x_vec", "a_vec"))
        val pipe = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(tr0, tr1, tr2, tr3)).fit(df)

        pipe.write.overwrite().save("/tmp/foobar")
    }

}
```

The exception message is :

```
org.json4s.Formats.emptyValueStrategy()Lorg/json4s/prefs/EmptyValueStrategy;
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json4s.Formats.emptyValueStrategy()Lorg/json4s/prefs/EmptyValueStrategy;
```

This repeats regardless of what pipeline you try to create, could it be related to [this](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues/212)?
What's going on?

Comment: Issue solved, the json4s version 3.2.11 was not used for some reason. once it was fixed everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved, the json4s version 3.2.11 was not used for some reason. once it was fixed everything is fine. –